# Isolate strings out of PHP array?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string, parsing

Let's say I have just selected from a MySQL database the string representation of a PHP array like this:

```
a:1:{s:2:"cc";a:2:{i:39340;s:9:"Username1";i:119778;s:9:"Username2";}}
```

How can I extract the strings "Username1" and "Username2" (or rather, all strings within the second set of curly braces), whose contents can be any ASCII string from this array (but not the string "cc")? Is there a straightforward way of doing this in PHP or do I need to use a regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). Why? because that string is actually a serialized array and that function will turn it back into an array.

```
$array = unserialize('a:1:{s:2:"cc";a:2:{i:39340;s:9:"Username1";i:119778;s:9:"Username2";}}');
print_r($array);

Array
(
    [cc] => Array
        (
            [39340] => Username1
            [119778] => Username2
        )

)
```

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.org/OixAC4qE)